# Existe algum algoritmo para checar a validade de um número de RG no Brasil usando dígitos verificadores?

Tags: algoritmo, brasil, validação

Existe algum algoritmo para checar a validade de um número de RG no Brasil usando dígitos verificadores, como acontece com o CPF? Caso afirmativo, como é esse algoritmo?

Comment: Um ótimo exemplo de pergunta que só faz sentido aqui, no *em Português* :)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Nacional? Não, o RG não tem numeração unificada. Um mesmo indivíduo pode ter RGs emitidos pelo governo local, pode também se utilizar de carteiras funcionais como o CREA ou o CRM ou identidades militares emitidas pelo Exército, por exemplo.

Possivelmente existe um algorítimo por orgão (alguém falou em mod 11), mas dúvido que exista um cadastro/registro de pares orgãos emissores e modos de validação.

Comment: Inclusive tem números de RG que o dígito verificador é 'X'

Comment: Verdade. De fato, o dígito não é considerado parte do RG (ou do CPF), servindo apenas para validação de digitação.

Comment: Existem inclusive números de RG sem DV

Answer (score 18):

Não é Padrão, cada estado é Livre sobre a Emissão de RG, o formato varia de estado para estado, se for realmente necessário validar o RG, faça como a maioria que vejo, peça a foto ou scan do documento.

Pra todos os sistemas que fiz que precisavam de validação usei o CPF, por ser único

Answer (score 5):

Você pode validar se um número de RG é válido através de um algoritmo sim, conforme já citado anteriormente. Detalhes neste [site](http://vestibular.uol.com.br/ultnot/resumos/ult2774u16.jhtm), onde são explicados os cálculos passo a passo. Entretanto é fundamental realçar 2 pontos: o fato de o RG ser válido não significa que ele é existente, apenas que é consistente matematicamente; e cada Unidade da Federação (inclusive o Distrito Federal) cadastra seu Registro Geral de forma independente, de modo que uma pessoa pode ter até 27 Registros Gerais (embora esteja em andamento um processo de unificação gradual, o [RIC](http://www.brasil.gov.br/cidadania-e-justica/2010/12/conheca-o-novo-registro-de-identidade-civil-ric)).

P.S.: A despeito de cada UF emitir o RG de forma independente, o cálculo é o mesmo (exceto talvez em registros mais antigos, antes da padronização).

Comment: O detalhes do site devem ser específicos a um estado. O meu RG (PR) não foi validado corretamente.

Comment: Mas o seu RG foi emitido recentemente ou é antigo? Porque me parece que a padronização é relativamente recente.

Comment: Meu primeiro RG foi emitido há quase 20 anos. A numeração nunca mudou.

Comment: Pelo jeito a padronização foi só para os documentos emitidos a partir daquela data.

Comment: Até entendo que esse validor pode funcionar para RGs emitidos a partir de uma certa data, mas na minha opinião "sistemicamente" falando, um validador só deve ser implementado se ele for 100% eficiente, caso contrário isso pode causar transtorno para os usuários e administradores do sistema.

Answer (score 4):

O cálculo do dígito verificador do RG utiliza o módulo 11. O CPF utiliza o mesmo algoritmo duas vezes. Mais detalhes:  http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%ADgito_verificador

Comment: Esse outro link também pode ser de bastante ajuda. :) http://www.profcardy.com/cardicas/rg.php

Comment: Isso não é verdade para muitos estados, inclusive tem RGs mais antigos que sequer tem digito de validação.

Comment: Sim, @NetoMarin, você tem razão. Mas a pergunta é sobre como a validação com dígitos é efetuada. Assim, quando o dígito é utilizado, o seu cálculo é normalmente efetuado com o módulo 11.

Answer (score 0):

RG's são registros emitidos pelo estado(UF).
Cada estado têm regras e quantidades diferentes de números no registro.
Não é uma fonte confiável para garantir a unicidade de um dado.

Por isso, existem diversos algoritmos como alguns aqui já citados.

Comment: Veja isso: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/508/o-que-fazer-com-respostas-duplicadas