# Consultar RG no banco de dados ignorando pontuações

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho um banco de dados mysql onde preciso fazer uma comparação de RGs cadastrados com um outro fornecido pelo usuário através de um input, para ver se já está cadastrado o mesmo RG no banco.

O problema é que como tem registros com pontuações no RG e outros sem pontuação, não existe um padrão. Neste caso, pensei em tirar as pontuações que recebo do input e comparar com o que tenho no banco, pela minha SQL, mas para isso preciso ignorar as pontuações que já tenho na coluna RG no meu banco.

Como posso fazer isso em minha SQL?

---

<sup>**Nota aos portugueses:** RG (Registro Geral) é o documento oficial de identidade no Brasil. O formato da numeração varia de estado para estado, e isto gera uma série de problemas, inclusive a facilidade do cidadão brasileiro ter irregularmente RGs diferentes em estados diferentes. Houve um projeto de unificação do sistema trocando o RG pelo RIC, um novo formato padronizado, mas infelizmente o projeto foi suspenso.</sup>
<sub>Mais detalhes em http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cédula_de_identidade</sub>

Comment: Pela SQL? acho meio desnecessario, ja que voce esta fazendo um programa que se conecta ao mySQL, por que nao retirar esses acentos pelo programa? que liguagem esta usando, java, php? Mas se realmente quiser uma solucao, achei no SOen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630472/removing-nonnumerical-data-out-of-a-number-sql (esta em ingles, nao foi testado com MySQL mas deve funcionar)

Comment: Concordo, o problema é que já existem diversos registros antes mesmo do meu sistema rodar, é uma base de dados que já existia.

Comment: Obrigado @bfavaretto pela explicação/edição referente ao RG, inclusive isso é algo que eu tinha dúvida, sobre os possíveis formatos.

Comment: O formato do RG varia de estado pra estado, e pode ou não ter dígito. Em outras palavras, você tem que tomar cuidado ao armazenar e ao comparar, pois um número curto de RG armazenado com dígito pode se confundir com um RG maior de outra pessoa, porém sem dígito. Um RG tirado de uma habilitação em SP vem sem dígito, mas deve ser comparado igualmente com um copiado com dígito de outro documento, por exemplo. Pra piorar, há um pequeno risco de pessoas de estados diferentes terem o mesmo número.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71/valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-rg

Answer (score 10):

Você pode usar a função [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) do MySQL para substituir os pontos e traços por nada:

```
SELECT ...
FROM tabela
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(coluna, '.', ''), '-', '') = '123456789'
```

**Importante:** segundo [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38622/consultar-rg-no-banco-de-dados-ignorando-pontua%c3%a7%c3%b5es/38623#comment75207_38622) na pergunta, o formato dos RGs é mais complexo e pode variar por estado. Um número como 12345 pode tanto ser um RG sem dígito, quanto um RG 1234-5. Por isso o mais seguro seria isolar o dígito, e idealmente o estado, para evitar falsos positivos e falsos negativos.

Comment: @Zuul geralmente os numero do RG é algo como `52.159.67-9` então sim, apenas . e - podem ser removidos, mas acreido que um **trim()** deveria ser aplicado tambem, para garantir que a comparacao seja correta. (tanto no programa quanto no SQL. @bfavaretto não acha que seria interessante deixar um trim() na resposta?

Comment: @OlimonF. O trim pode ser necessário ou não. Eu faria isso antes de gravar no banco, e antes de passar a entrada para ser comparada na query.